# Force safari to open url in same tab by calling openURL method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, safari

I am opening my scanner app using deep-linking from safari browser. When scanning is done, I'm moving to back safari from app along with the scanned details.
In this case, scanned details are opening in new tab, but I want it to be opened in previous tab itself.
Here is my code

```
UIApplication *mySafari = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    NSString *backButtonUrl = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                           stringForKey:Back_Button_Url_Key];
    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",backButtonUrl];

    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:strURL];
    [mySafari openURL:myURL];
    exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `openURL` always causes Safari to open a new tab. This functionality extends to their default apps, such as when you open the same link in Mail twice, you get 2 tabs. This one you don't have control over. If you could tell them to return to Safari, you might be able to have some server-side code to reload, but it's probably best just to send them back to the new tab.

Comment: Thanks man. I already got this conclusion, but just had a thought that someone might help.